# writing javascripts function using jquery

Tags: jquery

Some template written using jquery is as follows . it is not working . Any suggestions to use jquery efficiently .

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquerycall/"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function()  
    {  
        self.setInterval("clock()",1000);  
        $("button").click(function()  
        {  
            clock;  
        });  
        function clock()  
        {  
            clock();  
            time=new Date();  
            var s = "<p>" + time + "</p>";  
            $(s).appendTo("div");  
        }
    });  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form method="post">  
<button type="button">Click Me</button>  
<div id="someid"></div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: clock is an infinite recursion **and** used in setInterval - can't be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function clock()   
{   
   //clock(); /* Remove this recursive call or you'll just get an infinite loop */
   var current = new Date(); /* Make sure to use var on variables */
   var s = "<p>" + current + "</p>";
   $('#someId').html(s); /* Assuming you want to set 'someId' to 's', not try and append all things that match s to every div */
} 

var clockStarted = false;
$("button").click(function()   
{   
   if (!clockStarted) /* You only need to set the clock to start once */
      setInterval(clock, 1000);  /* You only want the interval to start after you've clicked the button and you don't need 'self'. */
   clockStarted = true;

   //clock(); /* Said 'clock;' before */   
});
```

To summarise:

1. When you call a function, you need to call it with parentheses and optionally parameters (e.g. functionName(); instead of functionName). This applies to all JavaScript.
2. Imagine there is one little gnome happily running through your code. When he gets to a line he reads it and does it. So let's say you've called clock(). He gets there and goes "what now? Oh, I have to go to clock()".  So he goes to clock(). He gets there and goes "what now?" Oh, I have to go to clock()". See the pattern? He's going to keep doing this *forever*, but he never actually gets a chance to do the things that you want clock() to do, because the first thing he sees as soon as he reaches clock() is that he needs to go to clock().  This is called infinite recursion. What you really wanted was to say "every so often I want a little gnome to go to clock() and do the things in there" which is what setInterval does.
3. $(s).appendTo('div') selects all things that match 's' (which will be nothing) and appends them to all things that match 'div' (which is every div).  Instead, you want to select the div with 'someId': "$('#someId')", and append 's' to that: ".append(s);".  If you don't want to append but instead replace, you will want to use ".html" not ".append".

#### Edits

- Includes edits as per request.
- Includes the fixes to 'setInterval' and 'var time' which slipped past me as per [Anurag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020692/writing-javascripts-function-using-jquery/3020818#3020818). I'm not trying to take credit for these fixes, but just wanted to include as part of a comprehensive answer given the other changes to meet the OP's comment.

Comment: The code is suppose to display current time continously once the button is clicked . for which I have used setInterval function .
The code works fine if I use only javascript. But I am not getting syntaxes to do the same thing using jquery

Comment: This should meet your requirements. If it doesn't let me know. If it does, make sure to "accept the answer" by clicking the tick next to this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such valuable explanation

Comment: Welcome, please remember to mark this as the accepted answer by "ticking" if you find it meets your needs more than any other and let me know if anything needs further explaining.

Comment: thanks :-) I find ridiculous examples take your mind off of the terminology and focus them on the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes I made while adding your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj7cE/):

1. Why call clock() inside clock without any base condition. It will run into an infinite loop. I've commented it out.
2. `time = new Date()` adds time to the global object. You should probably add a `var` before it to keep things local to the function.
3. When setInterval is called with the string "clock()" as a parameter, a `ReferenceError` gets thrown because clock is only defined in the outer anonymous function. However, when the inline code "clock()" is actually executed, it has no knowledge of the scope of that anonymous function, or the clock function. You should pass a reference to the function object itself, instead of passing a string, so when the timeout occurs, the reference is intact.
4. Why did you put a `self.setInterval()`? I couldn't see self being declared anywhere else. Unless `self` is pointing to `window` or it's your custom object wrapper around `window.setInterval`, that will throw a `ReferenceError` because you are calling a method on an undefined object (self).

Updated Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function clock() {
        // clock(); // infinite loop
        var time = new Date();  // global leak
        var s = "<p>" + time + "</p>";
        $(s).appendTo("div");
    }

    setInterval(clock, 1000); // self?

    $("button").click(function() {  
        clock(); // call function
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute clock() in intervals after the button click then you can do something like this

```
    $(function()   
    {   
        $("button").click(function()   
        {   
            setInterval (clock, 1000);   
        });   
        function clock()   
        {   
            time=new Date();   
            var s = "<p>" + time + "</p>";   
            $(s).appendTo("div");   
        } 
    });
```

This will run `clock()` at an interval of 1000 when the button is clicked.

Comment: Don't forget you probably don't want multiple button clicks to spawn multiple timers.

Comment: Also my js isn't strong but would there be a reference issue as button refers to clock before clock is declared?